# Selenium github actions IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed exception

Tags: selenium, github, internet-explorer, github-actions, selenium-iedriver

I am using Selenium to automate my Internet Explorer application in Github actions. When I try to run it I get the error message:

`This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed exception. The error returned is: Received error: 0x800700aa ['The requested resource is in use.'] web.get("URL");`

I've tried to set `ignore_protected_mode_settings` but it doesn't change anything.

I've also tried to change `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE` via workflow script but it seems like github actions doesn't give permissions for changing registres.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE WebDriver do you use? It's recommended to use the 32 bit version which can be downloaded [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). After downloading the WebDriver, you need to place it in your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

The last but not least, you need to meet all these [Required Configuration](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/#required-configuration) before executing the automation. Please check them one by one and make sure you meet all the requirements.

Comment: Yeah I have the 32b one. How can I edit Protected Modes from the github actions/selenium?

Comment: Due to security reasons, you can't configure Protected Mode from code. You can only configure the setting in [Internet Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Yvy.png) then run IE automation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it via github actions somehow? I've tried to find it but IE is not so popular for this use case, so no luck so far

Comment: I'm not familiar with GitHub Actions. I only know that we can't configure Protected Mode setting in Selenium. I suggest you can ask this in [GitHub Community](https://github.community/) to get more help.